is there any issue with jz command
%macro printdata 2
 mov eax,4
 mov ebx,1
 mov ecx,%1
 mov edx,%2
 int 80h
 %endmacro

 %macro readdata 2
 mov eax,3
 mov ebx,0
 mov ecx,%1
 mov edx,%2
 int 80h
 %endmacro

 section .text
   global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
     _start:                     ;tell linker entry point
      printdata prompt,length
      readdata number,1
      xor ah,ah
      xor ch,ch
      mov cl,[number]
      sub cl,30h
      mov dx,cx
      mov ax,dx
      mov bl,02h
      div bl
      mov cl,al
      mov ax,dx
      dec cl
 l1:div bl
    cmp ah,00h
    jz end
    inc bl
    dec cl
    jnz l1
    printdata prime,length2
    jmp exit
 end:
   printdata notprime,length3
exit: mov eax,1
  mov ebx,0
  int 80h

section .data
  prompt:db "Enter the number",0ah
  length equ $ -prompt
  prime:db "Number is prime"
  length2 equ $ - prime
  notprime:db "Number is not prime"
  length3 equ $ - notprime
section .bss
  number resb 1
  test1 resb 1


so i was trying to find prime numbers in one digit and when 9 is given it says it is prime could anyone explain why the jz end not working
note: Dont mind the logic of the code which cannot used for 1-3 and 2 digit numbers

I was expecting to get 9 is not prime.i did try with loop initially but it gives some floating error so I used dec cl,jnz l1

Inside the loop you forgot to reload ax. Move the mov ax, dx to l1:

Thanks .I dont see a upvote option(I dont know why) for your comment or I would have done that ..I was struggling with this code for some time now
